# selfish how to call parent initializer

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using selfish javascript library to make inheritance in javascript easier.
For example I have two Objects

```
var Foo = Base.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.some_param = 1;
      }
    }),
    Bar = Base.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.another_param = 2;
      }
    });
```

How to call from Bar initializer the Foo initializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Foo = Base.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.some_param = 1;
      }
    }),
    Bar = Base.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        Foo.initialize.call(this); // <------- here
        this.another_param = 2;
      }
    });
```